# Reading binary file of lake depths in R

Tags: r

I am trying to open a file in R, which is binary and written in Fortran. The file is called `GlobalLakeDepth.dat` and is available at: http://www.flake.igb-berlin.de/gldbv2.tar.gz

The instructions specify that to open `GlobalLakeDepth.dat` (in Fortran), one would need to do the following:

```
An example of opening the binary file in FORTRAN90:
-- open(1, file = 'GlobalLakeDepth.dat', form='unformatted', access='direct', recl=2)

An example of reading the binary file in FORTRAN90:
-- read(1,rec=n) LakeDepth
-- where: n - record number, INTEGER(8);
          LakeDepth - mean lake depth in decimeters, INTEGER(2).
```

My question is: Given these instructions in Fortran, how can I open this file in R?  That is, is there an 'R way' of doing this?

I've been following the instructions at http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/faq/read_binary.htm, but, am still not any closer to getting anything from the data file. All I need is the information provided on the measured lake bathemetry for 36 large lakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `readBin` to read a binary file. For this file, I think the correct command is

```
lk <- readBin("GlobalLakeDepth.dat", n = 43200 * 21600, what = "integer", endian = "little", size = 2)
```

This makes a **very long** vector that could be made into a 43200 * 21600 matrix.